# Where to configure network options

Tags: linux, unix

With most Linux/Unix you have the ability to configure, for example, DNS servers in 2 places. You can set it on the network interface configuration or you can set it in the traditional resolv.conf.

Staying with DNS, most distros recommend configuring it via the interface configuration script which is different among distros. Like Ubuntu uses /etc/network/interfaces and RHEL uses /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/.

Why is this the recommended location when resolv.conf would be much more universal?

Also I find it troubling placing anything other than Ethernet and IP options (layer 2 & layer 3 options) in the interface configuration. Everything else ( like DNS, Hostname, NTP, ...) belongs in its own /etc location in my opinion.

But this has sparked a debate among my colleagues and I would like more answers.

Comment: So I agree this question is off-topic. How do I move it over to Server Fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian has some explanations here:  https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration section "Defining the (DNS) Nameservers".

Basically, the `/etc/resolv.conf` should not be used in modern Desktop Linux distributives because several programs may overwrite it, if installed and active: `resolvconf`, `network-manager` and dhcp clients.

But on the server installation, there can be no such program and no DHCP. In such cases you can manually edit resolv.conf.

Comment: I like that method of reasoning. For servers use the traditional locations, for desktops use the distro specific modern locations